# How to read list item of same list group?

Tags: interop, vsto, office-interop

I would like to read my Word.ListFormat by hierarchy level in docx file by Word.Interop.

for Example, the below list not applied by outline or/and indent to read by hierarchy

```
1. Item 1 of Level 1 List
   a. Item 1 of Level 2 List
   b. Item 2 of Level 2 List
   c. Item 2 of Level 2 List

2. Item 2 of Level 1 List
   a. Item 1 of Level 2 List
      1. Item 1 of Level 3 List
      2. Item 1 of Level 3 List

   b. Item 2 of Level 2 List
   c. Item 2 of Level 2 List

3. Item 3 of Level 1 List
```

My Expectation to read the List by hierarchy, I don't want to read by sequence of paragraph.

First reading: Item 1 of Level 1 List
Second reading: Item 2 of Level 1 List
Third reading: Item 3 of Level 1 List

Once reading complete the Level 1, then need to read Level 2 list.

[image]

Here, I have attached the sample screen shot of docx list file.

Comment: I think you need to use regular expression to find its match and read the strings

Comment: Thanks Kiru, I found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for supporting,

I found the answer of the question.

```
    foreach (Word.Paragraph firstItem in document.Content.ListParagraphs.OfType<Word.Paragraph>().Reverse())
    {
        if (firstItem.Range.ListFormat.List != null)
        {
            foreach (Word.Paragraph item in firstItem.Range.ListFormat.List.ListParagraphs)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```